# Convert dynamic variable to string and check null or empty

Tags: c#, .net

I have a method like this:

```
public void TestMethod(dynamic details)
{
   string det = (string)Convert.ToType(details,typeof(string))

}
```

I want to check String.IsNullOrEmpty(details). For this I need to convert it from object to string.

I tried:

```
string det = (string)Convert.ToType(details,typeof(string))
```

It is throwing error:

> "Object must implement IConvertible"

I cannot implement this interface in class as it is written by another team.

Anyway to check "details" as null or empty?

Comment: `dynamic` is a pain in the neck in a lot of ways. Must it be `dynamic`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled It has to be dynamic as per specifications

Comment: Well if you don't even care to which string to convert - just call details.ToString().

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those sample inputs.

Comment: You need to find out what is the **actual underlying type** (or types, if it can vary), and then use whatever properties it may have to construct the string that you want. Nothing in .NET is ever going to find out that part for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `details` really is a `string`, there is no need to convert it:

```
string detailAsString = (string)details;
```

If it is not, you have to cast it to the actual type and perform some magic on it, since you can't call `Convert.ChangeType` with no specified way of converting.

You should really consider if you need `dynamic`. If you don't know the type `object` is even better than `dynamic`.

Comment: details will come as string or concatenated value

Comment: When using string detailAsString = (string)details;, it is throwing exception: "Cannot convert from object to string".

Comment: What is `details.GetType()` when that exception is thrown?

Comment: @mjwills It is 'object'

Comment: So not `string` then (despite your earlier statement). You need to call `details?.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution but comments code formatting is too limited for my suggestion:

```
public void TestMethod(dynamic details)
{
   string det = null;
   var convertible = details as IConvertible;
   if(convertible != null)
   {
       det = (string)Convert.ToType(details,typeof(string))
   } 
   else if(details != null)
   {
       // not so good since you have to relay on implementation...
       det = details.ToString(); 
   }

   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(det))
   {
       // the rest of the code goes here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well,  you can check them seperately.

```
public void TestMethod(dynamic details)
{ 
    if(details != null)
    {
      string det = details.ToString();
      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(det)) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(details)))
{
   // Do something if null
}else
{
// Do something if not null
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If details is a string, you don't need to convert it.
If details can be null, then :

```
if ((details as string) != null && details != "")
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Not checking null or empty

Comment: Please, have a look : https://dotnetfiddle.net/CC8R0s    I edited since I forgot to check for empty string

Comment: Actually I am testing method using Swagger. From there when method is called with no value in details textbox of swagger, it is not checking null or empty.

Comment: Somehow it is bypassing String.IsNullOrEmpty and conditions which you have mentioned.

Comment: Well, try to give more details about "details" ^^, what it is, what you're doing with it etc ? Provide an example if possible, so we can check